# Hello World Displayed as field response in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, graphql, mongoose-schema

I'm tring to simply save and return that custom data type

```
mutation{
  signUp(email:"sdc") {
    id,
    empId
  }
}
```

and getting improper response. However, on console logging I get the proper output but the final response is as follows.

```
{
  "data": {
    "signUp": {
      "id": "58de9b20772ffc7fe65db764",
      "empId": "Hello World"
    }
  }
}
```

I tried to search the `Hello World` string but could not find the string in whole project and this value is not stored in database. It seems that this is some default value that is fetched but I'm unable to get a trace of that.

Comment: please add the `signUp` mutation in Question

Comment: ```    signUp(email: String, displayName : String, empId : String, password : String) : User
```
@p0k8_

Comment: mutation field with type and resolver

Comment: export async function signUp (root, args, ctx) {
    let user = new UserModel(args
    );
    console.log("User is", user);
    user.save();
    return user;
}

Type is

export const typeDef = `
    type User {
        id: ID!
        email: String
        displayName: String
        password: String
        empId: String
    }
`;
export interface User {
    email: string | null;
    displayName: string | null;
    password: string | null;
    empId: string | null;
};

Comment: why are returning the user instance, i guess you have to return the saved data, which is `doc`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In apollo-graphql, when you use [`addMockFunctionsToSchema`](http://dev.apollodata.com/tools/graphql-tools/mocking.html), it returns a random string for type `ID` and `Hello World` for type `String` - and None of your resolvers will be called when you enable mocking.

So, you might have mocking enabled.